# Pushing and Popping view controllers - animation

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, push

I'm using a navigation controller for my app, because a lot of my views are hierarchical. However, I want to push a settings view when someone presses a button. However, I don't want to animate right to left, since I don't want to give the impression to the user that settings are a child of the view below it in the stack.

Is there any way I can animate the view change from bottom to top?

Or another way to switch views easily. Pushing and Popping views is so easy!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a the modal view controller, which by default will transition from bottom to top:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

where `modalViewController` is the view controller you want to slide from bottom to top, and animated is `YES`.

Comment: thanks, but it's a different approach. Is there any way to make the animation appear from bottom to the top _with_ UINavigationController?